# I have a range issue with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a button that moves a given number of cells from one sheet into another sheet. The starting range cell is always the same (A9) and there will be always 8 columns in total. The final row will depend on how many rows the user completes. How can I indicate this behaviour in my range code?

I think this needs to be instructed in `range` field, but couldn't obtain what I need.

```
function finishReport() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
  sheetName = sheet.getName(),
  data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 if (sheetName == "Main") {
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
  startRow = range.getRowIndex(),
  numRows = range.getNumRows(),
  numCols = range.getNumColumns()
 if (numCols == 8 {
  if (data.length > 1) {
   var values = range.getValues(),
    nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History record")
    lastRow = nextSheet.getLastRow();
   nextSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,numRows,8).setValues(values);
   sheet.deleteRows(startRow,numRows);
   } 
  } 
 } 
}
```

I expect that all rows entered by user in tab `Main` are moved to tab `History record`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query

- You want to copy a range starting at cell `A9` and stretching over 8 columns until the last row containing contents

### Problem

- You are using [`getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getActiveRange()) which returns you only the selected (=highlighted) range - if no range is highlighted in the sheet, only the active cell will be returned as a range

### Solution

- Select the range manually by retrieving the last content containing row and column with

```
mainLastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
mainLastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
```

and defining

```
var numRows = mainLastRow-startRow+1;
var numCols = mainLastColumn-startColumn+1;
```

### Full Code

```
function finishReport() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheetName = sheet.getName();

 if (sheetName == "Main") {
  var startRow = 9;
  var startColumn=1;
  var mainLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var mainLastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var numRows = mainLastRow-startRow+1;
  var numCols = mainLastColumn-startColumn+1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,numRows,numCols);
   Logger.log(numRows);
   Logger.log(numCols);
   Logger.log(mainLastRow);
   Logger.log(mainLastColumn);
  if (numCols == 8) {
   if (numRows >= 1) {
    var values = range.getValues();
    nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History record");
    lastRow = nextSheet.getLastRow();
    nextSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,numRows,8).setValues(values);
    sheet.deleteRows(startRow,numRows);
   } 
  } 
 } 
}
```

### Annotation

- You could also retrieve the range with [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), but you would have to correct manually for the fact that `dataRange` starts by definition in cell `A1`.

Comment: This worked fantastically fine! Thanks for the explanation. Javi.-

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Report')
      .addItem('Finish', 'FinishReport')
      .addToUi();
}

function FinishReport(){
  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = sp.getActiveSheet();
  var as =sp.getSheetByName('Main').activate(); 
  var MainRange = sp.getRange('A9:H9').activate();
  var MainLastRow = sp.getLastRow();    
  var selection = sp.getRange('A9:H' + MainLastRow).activate();
  sp.getCurrentCell().activateAsCurrentCell();
  sp.setActiveSheet(sp.getSheetByName('History record'), true);
  var lastRow = sp.getLastRow();
  var newRow = lastRow+1;  
  sp.getRange('A'+newRow+':H'+newRow).activate();
  sp.getCurrentCell().activateAsCurrentCell();  
  sp.getRange('Main!' + selection.getA1Notation()).moveTo(sp.getActiveRange());  
}
```

**REFERENCE**

[Spreadsheet Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopene)

[Apps Script, SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)